# The cursor.getCount() returns 0 when searching audio files from the external storage in emulator

Tags: android, cursor, audio-player, android-external-storage

I am working on a media player app on Android Studio. I am using a function that loads audio files from the external storage using a Cursor. I have set all the permissions in the Manifest file and also implemented the function

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult()
```

There is no error regarding permissions.
Just the cursor count returns 0. Is this because I am using an emulator or something's wrong in the code. 
Here is the relevant code snippet

```
private void loadAudio() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);
    Log.i("Cursor Count=",cursor.getCount()+"");
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        audioList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            // Save to audioList
            audioList.add(new Audio(data, title, album, artist));

        }
    }

    cursor.close();
}
```

Can anyone help. Thanks!

Comment: No music files on the emulator.

Comment: @blackapps Like, we cannot search files located on the emulator using our code?

Comment: ??? Are there music files on the emulator?

Comment: Yes I have put one to test the app. I dragged and dropped an mp3 into the Genymotion Emulator. It is stored in SD Card/ Downloads Location. And by the way, I found out that my app works on phone but it can't find the files on emulator.

Comment: The Download location is certainly not on the SD card but on external memory. If you put it in a Download folder then why ask the MediaStore for it? You know where it is. The MediaStore mostly only knows about new files after reboot.

Comment: I mean, I just put it in Downloads to test the app. The music files can be anywhere, so MediaStore is necessary. I think Genymotion doesn't support this. Because when I added a picture just to see it in the Genymotion Gallery, it showed nothing.

Comment: I just told you why you do not yet find it in the MediaStore.

Comment: Isn't SD card the external storage?

Comment: If you say SD card then for a real device its a micro SD card and hence removable external storage. Not everry device can take a micro SD card. But every device has external memory on board. So internal memory is called external storage. Yes yes.

Comment: @blackapps Alright then, thanks for your info!